# How do I use the updated UIImagePickerControllerDelegate iOS 12 API?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios12

How do I use the updated `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` API since it changed to `[UIIMagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`? This part has been  updated. I also searched here and I could not find an answer.

```
import UIKit

class adicionarNovoItemVc: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldNome: UITextField!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var namePreview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagePreview: UIImageView!
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func botaoAdcFoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        ???
    }
}
```

Update:

After updating the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate to :

```
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage? {
        self.imagePreview.image = image

        self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I now get:

> Cannot downcast from 'Slice>' to a more optional type 'UIImage?'

Comment: I redid your edit because you made the existing answers obsolete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really much different. In iOS 12, lots of the old constants names have been refactored.

Instead of the old key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` you now use `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage`:

Something like:

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
```

now becomes:

```
let image = info[.originalImage]
```

See the related documentation for [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey).

Update:

You made several mistakes in your attempted `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. You need:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imagePreview.image = image
    }

    self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement your suggestion, but I got an error. I just updated the code, can you check for me?

Comment: See my updated answer. You has several mistakes. You had the wrong signature for the delegate method and your `if let` was wrong.

Comment: Hello, I replace my code using your update. However, I got this error: Value of type 'UIImageView?' has no member 'setImage'

Comment: I got to fix saying self.imagePreview.image = image

Comment: It seems you blindly copied the invalid code from the other answer. You are well beyond the original issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **mediaTypes** of the picker using the **availableMediaTypes** class func of UIImagePickerController and retrieve the actual image from the **info** parameter.

```
@IBAction func botaoAdcFoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) {
          picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        }

        present(picker, animated: true)
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage? {
      self. imagePreview.setImage(image, for: .normal)

      self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```